# Cannot access children of JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, json

I have a JSON object musicianobj, an example of which I have pasted below:

```
{
id: "451026389391"
name: "John Frusciante"
type: "profile"
url: "http://open.spotify.com/artist/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

I got this from the Facebook API using the Javascript SDK. I can run `console.log(musicianobj);` which successfully prints the object to the log in Chrome, but `console.log(musicianobj.name);`, `console.log(musicianobj[1]);`, and `console.log(musicianobj["name"]);` all return undefined for no apparent reason. Any ideas?

Edit: code below.

```
var playFriendsTrack = function(friend){
  FB.api("/"+friend+"/music.listens", function(data) {
    var songname = data.data[0].data.song.title;
    var artistname = "";
    FB.api(data.data[0].data.song.id,function(trackdata){
      var musicianobj = trackdata.data.musician;
      console.log(musicianobj);
      console.log(musicianobj["name"]); // Doesn't work
      console.log(musicianobj.name); // Doesn't work
      artistname = musicianobj[1]; // Doesn't work
    });
    if(artistname.length <= 0){
      alert("Error! Please try another friend.")
    }
    }
  );}
```

Comment: Are you decoding it from JSON before poking it?

Comment: try: console.log(typeof musicianobj);

Comment: is musicianobj a JSON array with a single element?  If so, all of you console.log() attempts would indeed fail.

Comment: Code is added, there are 4 elements in the musicianobj JSON array. Every other time I've used the Facebook JS SDK it returns JSON objects rather than strings, so I don't have to decode it. Also, see below, I tried decoding it using `JSON.parse()` and that didn't work.

Comment: and `console.log(typeof musicianobj)` returns 'object'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you decoded it? It seems it is still a string.

```
musicianobj = JSON.parse(musicianobj);
console.log(musicianobj.name); // Now this should work
```

Comment: Afraid it didn't work, I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token o`. As far as I know the Facebook SDK returns JSON objects rather than strings, because standard JSON access works. In fact, that object is taken from an object returned from the Facebook sdk, using the code `var musicianobj = trackdata.data.musician;`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! I had to put a `[0]` after `musicianobj`. Apparently I don't know JSON as much as I'd like to. The working code is pasted below:

```
var playFriendsTrack = function(friend){
FB.api("/"+friend+"/music.listens", function(data) {
  var songname = data.data[0].data.song.title;
  var artistname = "";
  FB.api(data.data[0].data.song.id,function(trackdata){
    var musicianobj = trackdata.data.musician;
    console.log(musicianobj);
    console.log(musicianobj[0]["name"]);
    console.log(musicianobj[0].name);
    artistname = musicianobj[0].name;
  });
  if(artistname.length <= 0){
    alert("Error! Please try another friend.")
  }
  }
);}
```